# How to efficiently import the contents of an html5 canvas into flash?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, html, html5-canvas

I have tried to use "ExternalInterface.call()" to invoke a javascript function that returns the contents of a canvas. However, for a relatively small canvas (256x256) this is extremely slow (around 2 seconds), seemingly because of the marshalling of arguments/return value.

Even if I break down the canvas data into smaller chunks, as suggested by Brad Neuberg in an older post (from 2006): http://codinginparadise.org/weblog/2006/02/how-to-speed-up-flash-8s.html , I still get a poor performance. The size of chunks should not be an issue as of Flash 9 anyway.

I guess I could still try to overwrite the Flash javascript functions that do the marshalling/evaluation of parameters, but this seems very involved and I wanted to know if I was missing anything simpler, before attempting that.

I also tried an older way to communicate flash and javascript by doing:

```
var req : URLRequest = new URLRequest("javascript:getImage()"); 
var loader : Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(req);
```

where "getImage()" is a javascript function that returns the contents of the canvas as an image. But this throws some sort of security violation error as no browser script is allowed to be used as target URL, unless one uses the "navigateToURL()" as opposed to the "Loader.load()" function. Unfortunately the former does not return a value.

I've also seen some older code using the "com.macromedia.javascript.JavaScriptProxy" class, but I have not tested it and it does not seem to be available in Flash 11.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Some time ago I wrote [flashcam](http://code.google.com/p/flashcam/) to capture webcam video on Flash and draw it after on a HTML5 canvas using JavaScript. After some tests, I finally use a bit complex schema with a String of comma separated values of consecutive pixel differences encoded using a base 36. Check the code, don't must be too hard invert the process.

Comment: @JuanMellado, Thanks for the hint. Definitely, the way in which you encode the image data makes a huge difference, and string is the way to go because in the end everything is passed in XML format. I ended up using a PNG compression + Base64 encoding which can be done very efficiently through the canvas function `canvas.toDataURL('image/png')`. This improved performance by some orders of magnitude compared to passing the image data as a pixel or byte array, which involves a __flash__toXML() call per pixel on the client side. Maybe I should post this as an answer, not sure, I'm new to SO.

Comment: Great. And yes, answer your own question then.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 options: one easy, one hard.

1) Round trip it to the server. It might be just as slow but it won't be prone to locking up Flash or causing a script timeout.

2) See if you can write an HTML5 WebSocket that can connect to Flash's LocalConnection. This is no small feat. [This guy](http://osflash.org/localconnection) seems to have cracked that nut in C. He made an app that can "speak" LocalConnection.

Comment: thanks for your reply. 1) is definitely more inefficient than handling everything on the browser side, so it's out of the question in this case. 2) I took a quick look and it doesn't seem to be any real way to do any TCP communication in JS. Everything I found is either simmulated TCP on top of http or some sort of hack like the link you give. The former is bound to an overhead similar to that of  the ExternalInterface Flash object, the latter, I can't even imagine the headaches it would give to get it to work on all platforms. Still, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Websockets can be done from JS, see this explanation http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/, but I don't think websockets are well matched to your use case, which sounds like a one time connection, rather then the long running open connection sockets are intended for.